# Vaadin Tree: Overlay or more icons

Tags: tree, icons, overlay, vaadin

does anybody have a solution for my problem? I need more icons for items in my Tree component.
Icons are useful for conveying item's node type, but I need to express its status or another properties. 
It would be ideal if Tree had methods like addItemIcon or addItemOverlayIcon.
Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set icon for item:

```
Tree tree = new Tree();
tree.addItem("MyItem");
tree.setItemIcon("MyItem", FontAwesome.ADJUST);
```

If there are not enough icons in FontAwesome you can always map your own or other iconset (as Resource).

One option of adding more icons inline is with adding ItemStyleGenerator:
Where you have reference to itemId, where you want add css style (into class attribute).

```
tree.setItemStyleGenerator(new ItemStyleGenerator()
{
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Tree source, Object itemId)
    {
        return " fa fa-road";
    }
});
```

Then you have to stylize it with your own CSS (map font icons to class selectors and use desirable css properties for size and color), it should look something like that:

```
.fa .fa-road span:BEFORE{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f018';
}
```

Comment: I can use single icon, but the question is: How to add two or more icons to one tree-item. Next to each one (before caption) or using overlaying on the same place with transparency.

Comment: Thank You, it is sufficient solution. In addition it can be enriched by colors.

Answer (score 0):

Beeing inspired by zigc, I tried another solution. Simply set

```
.v-tree-node-MyTree{font-family: FontAwesome, Arial}
```

Then I can include special characters from FontAwesome directly into the caption-text, at the beginning, at the end or anywehere in the middle. Unsupported (not included in FontAwesome) characters are displayed with the second font. 
An example with two more icons at the beginning or the caption:

```
int codePoint[]={FontAwesome.HOME.getCodepoint(),FontAwesome.ROAD.getCodepoint()};
tree.setItemCaption(itemId, new String(codePoint,0,2)+nodeName);
```